# Display selected values after form submission select 2 with php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, jquery-select2

I am using Multiple Select box of Select2.
After form submission i am saving values in database by wordpress.
The problem is how can i show the selected values in form field after getting from database. 
Code is below:

```
<select name="jws_ob_pages_show_name[]" class="spages" multiple="multiple">';

$pages = get_pages(array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'parent' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
foreach($pages as $page){
    $returner .= '<option value="'.$page->post_title.'">'.$page->post_title.'</option>';
}

$returner .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this just add 'selected' after value attribute

```
<select name="jws_ob_pages_show_name[]" class="spages" multiple="multiple">';

$pages = get_pages(array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'parent' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
foreach($pages as $page){
    $returner .= '<option value="'.$page->post_title.'" selected>'.$page->post_title.'</option>';
}

$returner .= '</select>';
```